# Elixir: Transform a symbol into a function

Tags: elixir

Is there a way to call symbols as functions, so something like the following code would work?

```
op = :+

3 = op(1,2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Code.eval_quoted/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Code.html?#eval_quoted/3)

```rb
{3, _} = Code.eval_quoted {:+, [], [1, 2]}
#⇒ {3, []}
```

---

In more sophisticated cases one might use [macros](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/macros.html) to achieve that functionality. Basically, macros do receive AST and *return AST* to be injected in place of the macro call.

```rb
defmodule Test do 
  defmacro op(o, a1, a2) do
    {o, [], [a1, a2]}
  end
end

require Test
Test.op :+, 1, 2
#⇒ 3
```

---

Also, you can use [`Kernel.apply/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#apply/3)

```rb
apply(Kernel, :+, [1, 2])
#⇒ 3
```

---

Making it work with dynamic operators is a bit tricky. Usually, for the regular functions, one would do something like

```rb
quote do
  unquote(o)(unquote(a1), unquote(a2))
end
```

but unfortunately, [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) compiler does not allow the syntax `+(1, 2)` for the operators. Somewhat like below would work, though.

```rb
defmodule Test do
  defmacrop op(o, a1, a2) do
    quote do
      {o, a1, a2} = {unquote(o), unquote(a1), unquote(a2)}
      {o, [], [a1, a2]}
      |> Code.eval_quoted()
      |> elem(0)
    end
  end

  def plus do
    o = :+
    {a1, a2} = {1, 2}
    op(o, a1, a2)
  end
end

IO.inspect(Test.plus())
#⇒ 3
```

Comment: I have updated the answer with the third possible way to achieve it.

Comment: actually the defmacro throws: `lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:229: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/7` if i use it in the same module

Comment: It looks like a flaky compiler takeover. It happens, try to recompile. If recompilation won’t help, please post the whole code of the module that throws, I cannot reproduce it here.

Comment: Ah the problem is: i don't understand elixir's macros.
if i use Test.op :+, 1, 2 everything works fine.
When i have :+ and 1 and 2 in some variables inside a function, so the compiler does not know what is it gonna be, and instead expands the macro with this variable `{{:o, [line: 9], nil}, [line: 9], ......}`.

Comment: Macros do receive AST as an input and produce AST as an output. The latter would be injected in place of the call. I have updated the answer with the working dynamic example, but in your case I would definitely go with `Kernel.apply/3` instead of macros. There are too many pitfalls and caveats to be aware of when using macros.

Answer (score 1):

Operators are present as auto-imported functions in the Kernel module, so you can use the `&` operator to get a reference to them:

```
op = &+/2
3 = op.(1,2)
```

Note the dot in the second line: in Elixir, variables and functions are in separate namespaces.  `op(1,2)` means calling the function named `op`, while `op.(1,2)` means calling the function that the variable `op` holds a reference to.